# Use dictionary instead of list of dictionary to reduce program complexity

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, environment-variables

Trying to validate the consistency between DynamoDB tables, Used list of dictionary to store dynamodb table items, Which is taking longer time for execution.

New to python, any help to convert List of dictionary to dictionary please, To reduce my program complexity .

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import boto3
import argparse
import argparse

def table_consistency_check(table, column_name):
    paginator = dynamoClient.get_paginator('scan')
    modified_accounts = []
    params = {
        'TableName': table
    }

    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**params)
    for page in page_iterator:
        for item in page['Items']:
            account = item['account_name']['S']
            license_key = item[column_name]['S']
            credentials = {
                'account_name': account,
                column_name: license_key
            }
            modified_accounts.append(credentials)

    return modified_accounts


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Find all accounts with different license key and account key hash')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--region', nargs='?', type=str, default='us-west-2')


    try:
        args = parser.parse_args()
    except:
        exit_code = int(str(sys.exc_info()[1]))

    accounts_table = 'accounts_table'
    Credentail_table = 'credential_table'
    dynamoClient = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name=args.region)
    account1 = table_consistency_check(accounts_table, 'license_key')
    account2 = table_consistency_check(Credentail_table, 'access_key_hash')
    output = []

    for acct_item in account1:
        for creds_item in account2:
            if acct_item['account_name'] == creds_item['account_name']:

                if creds_item['access_key_hash'].startswith('ORIGINAL_KEY_'):

                    val = creds_item['access_key_hash']
                    length = len('ORIGINAL_KEY_')

                    str = val[length:]

                    if acct_item['license_key'] != str:
                        output.append(creds_item['account_name'])
                        print('Duplicate record found')
                        print('Account Name : ' + acct_item['account_name'] + ', License Key : ' + acct_item[
                            'license_key'] + ', Access Key Hash : ' + creds_item['access_key_hash'])
    if not output:
        print('the tables are consistent, No duplicate item found')
```